# Самостоятельное предложение в скобках

Tags: пунктуация, вставная-конструкция

Обычно в скобках пишется какая-то ремарка, короткое пояснение, которое находится как бы вне основного предложения. Но мне попадались варианты, когда в скобках было целое предложение. Например:

*Я сперва хотел кроссовки, но Аркашина мама заметила, что если не известен точный размер, лучше взять сандалии-плетенки, у них можно регулировать задние ремешки. (И вообще для ангелов сандалии подходят больше, почти библейская обувь, подумал я. И внутри опять все ухнуло от фантастичности происходящего. Но… ухнуло и отпустило.)*
**[В. Крапивин. Прохождение Венеры по диску Солнца](https://www.litres.ru/vladislav-krapivin/prohozhdenie-venery-po-disku-solnca/chitat-onlayn/page-2/)**

Для чего вообще нужны скобки, если пояснения и так вынесены в отдельные предложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно вставные конструкции, имеющие добавочное значение и обособленные с помощью тире или скобок, вписываются  в структуру предложения. В то же время в некоторых случаях (значительная распространенность, раскрытие отдельной темы и др.) они могут оформляться в виде отдельных предложений, но при этом сохраняются скобки, определяющие вставной характер этих предложений.

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ПО ТЕМЕ

http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/256-vstavnyekonstrukcii.html?start=1

Вставная конструкция может оформляться как самостоятельное предложение. Такая конструкция выделяется скобками, причем точка, фиксирующая конец вставного предложения, ставится перед закрывающей скобкой.

Например:

(1)...Так будет дальновиднее... (У Маслова клокотало в горле, хотя говорит он тихо и даже вяло.) Ничего не изменилось, Екатерина Дмитриевна!.. Второе: ваш ночной гость сейчас уйдет... Вы хотите спросить – почему я настаиваю на этом? Вот мой ответ... (Он запустил руку в боковой карман засаленного, с оборванными пуговицами, пиджака, вытащил плоский парабеллум и, держа его на ладони, показал Кате.) Затем будем продолжать наши прежние отношения... (А. Т.);

(2) Никогда я не ел яиц вкуснее этих. (Конечно, это Витька придумал печь яйца. Всегда он что-нибудь придумывает, даром что уши торчат в разные стороны.) (Сол.).

Answer (score 1):

Мне нечего добавить к ссылкам и правилам, отмеченным *@Софией*, могу только привести некоторые дополняющие примеры ([**Роберт Гэлбрейт. Шелкопряд**](http://loveread.me/read_book.php?id=39241&p=31)):

*...пусть бы из них образовалось приемлемое для всех единое целое; пусть бы Страйк пришел на венчание и одобрил («одобрил»! С какой стати он должен одобрять?) ее брак с Мэтью.* [стр.18]

*В таком случае что она здесь делает? Почему отказалась от более денежного места? (В запальчивости Робин предпочла не вспоминать, насколько отталкивающей представлялась ей работа – пусть даже хорошо оплачиваемая – в отделе кадров.)* [стр.23]

*Его тактика допроса стала напоминать ловкое манипулирование фигурками в настольном футболе: пошатывающийся собеседник подчинялся точным, легким касаниям. (В семидесятые годы у Страйка был покупной «Арсенал», а у Дейва Полворта – расписанный на заказ «Плимут Аргайл»; лежа на коврике перед камином в доме матери Дейва, мальчишки устраивали футбольные баталии.)* [стр.91]